# how to resolve select2 warning message ? Already provide key and id but still error exist can anyone have idea about this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how I use my select2

```
<Select2 id="courseId" key={1} value={courseAttributeDisp} data={ courseAttributeList }/>
```

Comment: I don't think the key should go to your `Select2`. This warning occurs when you map through data and render it in the form of a list. Check out [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) from React docs

Comment: without key still same warning

Comment: Yes I meant that the keys should probably go to where your loop is. If you read the docs it will help to understand how to do this. What is the exact error you're getting?